# ClusteringComponent and FindClusters are returning the wrong number of clusters and are inconsistent

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I am trying to find the optimum number of clusters in a correlation matrix.

To do this I run a clustering algorithm that loops through 3 variables ( number of clusters, `Method` and `RandomSeeding`) and then select the best clustering from there.

However, while running these loops I run in to errors every now and then when `FindClusters` and `ClusteringComponents` return

1. **Inconsistent number of clusters**, i.e.: `FindClusters` returns 4 clusters and `ClusteringComponents` returns 5 clusters

OR

2. **Wrong number of clusters**, i.e.: both return 4 clusters when 5 clusters was requested

An example of when this happens is in snippet 2 when number of clusters = 5, `RandomSeeding=3` and `Method->"KMeans"`

```
(* ===DEFINE REQUIRED FUNCTION=== *)
properDistanceMatrix[corrMat_] := Sqrt[0.5*Chop[1. - corrMat]];

(* ===IMPORT DATA=== *)
importPath =(*your path update here*)"\\retMat.csv";
retMat = ToPackedArray[Import[importPath]];
used = retMat[[1 ;; 1008, 226 ;; 275]];
corMat = Correlation[used];
distMat = properDistanceMatrix[corMat];
allDistance = DistanceMatrix[distMat];

(* ===RUN CODE=== *)

(* ===snippet 1=== *)
cc = ClusteringComponents[distMat, 5, 1, Method -> "KMedoids", 
   RandomSeeding -> 3, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
fc = FindClusters[distMat, 5, Method -> "KMedoids", 
   RandomSeeding -> 3, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
Print[{First@Dimensions[fc], Max[cc]}];
(* correctly returns 5 clusters on both as specified above *)

(* ===snippet 2=== *)
ccBug = ClusteringComponents[distMat, 5, 1, Method -> "KMeans", 
   RandomSeeding -> 3, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
fcBug = FindClusters[distMat, 5, Method -> "KMeans", 
   RandomSeeding -> 3, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
Print[{First@Dimensions[fcBug],Max[ccBug]}];
(* returns {4,5} when 5 clusters were requested.  
returns {4,4} if snippet 1 is not run.
problem disappears when seed is changed (to 4 for example) and correctly returns {5,5} *)
```

Based on this thread [FindClusters versus ClusteringComponents?](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/960586) I was under the impression that `FindCluster` and `ClusteringComponents` had been rejigged to return the same number of clusters given the same inputs.

Is this a bug or am I using the functions wrongly?

Thanks

PS: I am running this on Windows 7 with Mathematica 11.2.0.0

EDIT : 
I realise that pointing to 3rd party sites for file hosting is frowned upon so I have added the following code that should replicate the same error

```
properDistanceMatrix[corrMat_] := Sqrt[0.5*Chop[1. - corrMat]];
retMatR = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 10}];

(*{{-0.420038, 0.477, 0.462921, -0.650315, -0.391649, 
  0.294729, -0.226934, -0.735427, 0.331658, -0.693274}, {-0.494563, 
  0.021645, 0.0178725, 0.266314, -0.986802, -0.0496106, -0.732457, 
  0.137578, 0.0482319, -0.616772}, {-0.073485, -0.655964, 
  0.00530954, -0.823253, 0.303467, 0.540479, 
  0.731417, -0.608943, -0.953788, 0.614624}, {0.403796, 
  0.895508, -0.354059, 0.0572363, 0.664937, -0.470154, -0.856749, 
  0.794929, 0.945532, 0.413173}, {-0.509987, 0.709611, 0.402642, 
  0.274048, -0.0804114, 0.261213, 0.205204, 0.754889, 
  0.406956, -0.701399}, {0.669529, -0.972304, -0.377802, 0.207726, 
  0.740803, -0.32163, 0.733927, 0.066348, 
  0.465975, -0.938974}, {0.485361, -0.987685, -0.525496, 
  0.965126, -0.802624, 0.232629, -0.660341, -0.0636777, 
  0.443938, -0.603204}, {-0.243766, -0.629372, 0.690897, 
  0.0910828, -0.192148, 0.272657, -0.124762, 0.591744, 0.0664948, 
  0.807557}, {-0.820118, -0.978278, -0.689691, 
  0.776383, -0.389317, -0.987641, 0.712486, -0.338271, 
  0.449278, -0.258858}, {-0.375498, -0.0127232, -0.148995, 0.754593, 
  0.720646, -0.0362857, 0.614544, 0.583437, 0.842111, 0.505644}}*)

Table[
  cc = ClusteringComponents[distMat, numClusters, 1, 
    Method -> "KMeans", RandomSeeding -> seed, 
    DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
  fc = FindClusters[distMat, numClusters, Method -> "KMeans", 
    RandomSeeding -> seed, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance, 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
  If[First@Dimensions[fc] != Max[cc], 
   Print[{{First@Dimensions[fc], Max[cc]}, {seed, numClusters}}]],
  {seed, 1, 25},
  {numClusters, 2, 9}
  ];

(*{{8,9},{25,9}}*)
```

[CSV file (retMat.zip) containing the 'retMat' matrix is available on this link.](https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/759690/retMat.zip)

Comment: I had this same issue with FindClusters not returning the requested number of components when using the second argument, for which I submitted [CASE:4092039]. Unfortunately, WRI replied that 'the second argument n in FindClusters[] instructs the function to determine at most n clusters and not exactly n clusters.'  So this is a 'feature' not a 'bug' - but obviously it is an entirely detrimental feature, and I requested that they improve the design to something more useful. If you also make a complaint/request along these lines it might actually get fixed...

Comment: Also, IIRC, the KMeans and the KMediods 'Methods' were both unstable, but the Agglomerate was (more?) consistent.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it returns "at most" n clusters which addresses point 2 above. 

Now we still have the problem that the ClustersComponents returned are inconsistent with FindClusters. 

I have contacted Wolfram about this too and will highlight your point above and post any updates here.

Comment: This might be helpful for consistency instead of using ClusteringComponents

`fc=FindClusters[data];`

`alternativeClusterComponents=DeleteCases[Flatten[Table[If[MemberQ[fc[[#]],x],#]&/@Range[Length[fc]],{x,data}]],Null]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wolfram has reponded confirming that "the number `n` form `FindClusters[data, n]` or `ClusteringComponents[data,n]`  is the actual maximum number of clusters, the data might be placed in less than `n` clusters" and also "that changing `RandomSeeding` indeed produces different results."

---

### Update August 2022

I'm happy to report that [as of version 13.1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html#1811902644):

> The clustering family (`FindClusters`, `ClusterClassify`,
> `ClusteringComponents`) now treats the syntax `f[data,n]` to signify that
> data has to be partitioned in exactly `n` clusters. To get back the old
> behavior that treated `n` as an upper limit, one can use
> `f[data,UpTo[n]]`.

Personally, a great upgrade which I find much more intuitive!